# What was Rabbi Akiva doing during the Quietus Revolt

Tags: rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef

Between 115 and 117 the Jews revolted against the Romans in Libya, Cyprus, and Israel, killing hundreds and thousands. This revolt was crushed by the Romans but the distraction caused them to fail to capture Mesopotamia from the Parthians.

Rabbi Akiva would have recently finished his 24 years of study during this period. Given that he is said to have been the "Rebbe" of the Bar Kochba revolt, I am interested in his activities during this earlier revolt.

Is there any tradition on the subject?

Comment: Likely no tradition. It's not even clear that the Jews in the Land of Israel even took part in that revolt.

Comment: In addition, Rabbi Akiva was probably not taking part in public affairs then.

Comment: Why wouldn't he be involved in public affairs?